# How to make Aiogram send an image from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

In my bot, I generate an image with three variables. Then, I want to send the image to user. I tried this code:

```
...

module.full_card(int(userid),tested_word[1],correct_word)
await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, photo=f"userdata/{userid}/output.png")

...
```

The first line works well: it created the image in the manner and directory needed.

As for the second, it gives me this error:

```
    Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-26' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Wrong http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\handlers\user_handlers.py", line 519, in check_start_ikb
    await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, photo=f"userdata/{userid}/output.png")
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 565, in send_photo
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\vlad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I made it!

Instead of the second line, I wrote this:

```
with open (f"userdata/{userid}/output.png", "rb") as photo_file:
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, photo=photo_file)
```

And it works :)